# Formatting date from field

Tags: gwt, date-formatting

I use SmartGwt and I have the following line:

```
formItem.getForm().getField("report_date").getValue().toString();
```

This returns something like this: *Tue Mar 27 12:00:00 EEST 2012*

Thing is I need it formated like **DateDisplayFormat.TOUSSHORTDATE** (Short date in format MM/DD/YYYY).

Any suggestions on this? I tried a couple of things but didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format your Date object on the client side like this:

```
DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DateTimeFormat.PredefinedFormat.HOUR24_MINUTE).format(myDate);
```

The PredefinedFormat enum contains some usefully predefined formats. If none of those fits you needs, you can define your own.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). That can be used for parsing the original format as well as outputting in the second one.

Edit: It seems you already have a date (before calling toString). That makes things a bit easier. You can create the second format as `new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 1):

Any date formatting in java see this 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
    String sff = "Tue Mar 27 12:00:00 EEST 2012";

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");

    Date myDate = null;
    try {
        myDate = dateFormat.parse(sff);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);
```